# push notification for my android chat application

Tags: android, push-notification, chat

iam developing a chat application and now am on it's push notification part.. And now am in a big confusion.. because in my previous application iam using Google's GCM like, whenever i get a notification from the GCM server i pull data from my server.But in this case i think it's not the right way for a chat because if i try to do like this i have to connect the socket again and user will become in online status.And also am using raw socket for my application.

is there a better way for accomplishing this?

thank you

Comment: Check : https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: @HareshChhelana i know this ...my question is how i can effectively use this with my socket connecttion

Comment: so what is you have try so far ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana  the same thing i did for my previous application...please read my question

Answer (score 0):

I am using web socket for push notifications. In my android application (client side) I use Autobahn web socket client. It works fine, but if you want reliable solution then I think you can go for Azure Push Notification Service. But I think you can only send/receive few push notifications using their free service. To scale further you need to pay.

But using web socket you can send as many number of notifications as you want. Further, you can keep the connection always on, so that you don't need to reconnect the socket connection every time. But to ensure the active web socket connection you need implement PingPong. And that PingPong might use some the bandwidth.

Comment: thanks for your answer , actually my question is how we can use gcm for this purpose